# El significado de "HD" (alojamiento y desayuno)

Tags: abreviaturas

¿Qué significa la abreviatura "HD" en la siguiente frase? Supongo que D significa desayuno ... ¡Muchas gracias!

[AD o HD: alojamiento y desayuno.](https://www.logitravel.com/preguntas-frecuentes/hoteles-que-significa-sa-ad-mp-pc-ti-sp-hm-en-el-bono-del-hotel-8_172.html)

Answer (score 1):

"HD" significa, según el documento que se encuentra en [www.innsistondemand.com/elearning/manuals/IE1.1/es/Reservaciones.pdf](http://www.innsistondemand.com/elearning/manuals/IE1.1/es/Reservaciones.pdf), "habitación y desayuno".

En otros sitios, también aparece como "hospedaje y desayuno" ("hospedaje" es sinónimo de "alojamiento").